# How can I use class factor in function?

Tags: c++

```
void Str::operator=(char* a)
    {
        delete[] str;

        len = strlen(a);
        str = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy (str, a);

}

void Str::operator=(class Str a)
{
    delete[] str;

    len = strlen(a.str);
    str = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(str, a.str);


}
```

This is kind of class Str. I defined 'operator=(char *a) in class Str', and I can use first one in 'main.cpp' like this:

```
Str a("Icecream");
a = "Cake\n";
```

And run well.

But How I can use 'operator=(class Str a)' ?

I tried like this:

```
Str c("Hamburger")l

c = a;
```

I expected c has information of a. i,e, c is no longer hamburger information. c is Cake.

But when I compile this code, c does have information of a but call error.

How I can use' operator=(class Str a)'?

Comment: Please, make this answerable - proper formatting, no typos and **the error message**.

Comment: `char*`? This is C++, in 2016. Don't use `char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare it like this:

```
void Str::operator=(const Str& a)
```

The assignment operator requires a reference to its right operand (therefore `&`) and does not modify it (therefore `const`).